# java soap asmx basic authentication

Tags: java, soap, asmx

I want to use an .asmx SOAP web service from java by sending and object.
The service also uses basic authentication.
I have successfully marshalled the object to xml and tried to send using below methods.

I have tried the following methods to do the same:

```
URL url = new URL("https://api.sandbox.ewaypayments.com/Soap.asmx?wsdl");
httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
httpURLConnection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + encodedString);
httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
httpURLConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", String.valueOf(xml.length()));
httpURLConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "text/xml");
httpURLConnection.setRequestProperty("SoapAction", "");
httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
httpURLConnection.setUseCaches(false);
httpURLConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "text/xml");
PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(httpURLConnection.getOutputStream());
pw.write(postParameter);
pw.flush();
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(httpURLConnection.getInputStream()));
String line = "";
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
{
     responseMessage.append(line);
}


Call call = new Call("https://api.sandbox.ewaypayments.com/Soap.asmx");
call.setOperationName(new QName("https://api.sandbox.ewaypayments.com/", "CreateAccessCode"));
call.setSOAPActionURI("https://api.sandbox.ewaypayments.com/CreateAccessCode");
String strResult = (String) call.invoke(new Object[] { new CreateAccessCodeRequest()});
```

But i am getting 500 Error from server from the above methods.
I know that there is no problem at server side because the php calls are working fine. I just cant get it to work with java.
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I have made some progress by using the following method and managed to remove the error.

```
String loginPassword = username + ":" + password;
String encodedString = Base64.encodeBase64String(loginPassword.getBytes());
String xmlData = "";
String data = "";
BufferedReader br1 = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("D:\\reqfile.xml"));
while ((data = br1.readLine()) != null)
{
    xmlData += data;
    System.out.println(data);
}

DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
dbFactory.setNamespaceAware(true);
DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = dBuilder.parse(new File("D:\\reqfile.xml"));

SOAPConnectionFactory soapConnectionFactory = SOAPConnectionFactory.newInstance();
SOAPConnection soapConnection = soapConnectionFactory.createConnection();

MessageFactory messageFactory = MessageFactory.newInstance();
SOAPMessage soapMessage = messageFactory.createMessage();

soapMessage.getMimeHeaders().addHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + encodedString);
soapMessage.getMimeHeaders().addHeader("SOAPAction", "https://api.ewaypayments.com/CreateAccessCode");

SOAPPart soapPart = soapMessage.getSOAPPart();
SOAPEnvelope soapEnvelope = soapPart.getEnvelope();

SOAPBody soapBody = soapEnvelope.getBody();
soapBody.addDocument(doc);

soapMessage.saveChanges();

SOAPMessage reply = soapConnection.call(soapMessage, "https://api.sandbox.ewaypayments.com/Soap.asmx");

TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
Source sourceContent = reply.getSOAPPart().getContent();
StreamResult result = new StreamResult(System.out);
transformer.transform(sourceContent, result);
```

Now the server returns me the following error:

soap:Client
            Bad Arguments

I am unable to find which arguments are wrong. Is there a way to find out the exact error message description?
I have tested it in SoapUI and i got the same error but it also gave me some description about that error and due to that i got to solve the error in SoapUI and got the correct response. But i am unable to do the same using code.

Comment: did you find something ?